# How to force using night/day resources in a widget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-theme, android-appwidget

I need to show an app widget in the day, night or system theme. All colors are defined through resources.
How to ignore system theme and force using "day" or "-night" resources? I know that's possible within an activity but what about widgets?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @jsmart no, I use the workaround. I created day and night separate resources and use them through themes.